# Since upgrade to 20.04 problems with Intel graphics

Tags: kernel, screen, hdmi, intel, 20.04

since my upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Ubuntu 19.10 the HDMI output to the television screen does not work anymore. It isn't even recognized. I think that has something to do with the new kernel and the following error prompts on startup:

```
23:53:10 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
    23:53:03 systemd: Failed to start Tracker file system data miner.
    23:52:50 kernel: hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
    23:52:50 kernel: i915: `' invalid for parameter `enable_dpcd_backlight'
    23:52:49 kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
    23:52:49 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PAGD._STA due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

Using the old Kernel 5.3 it worked (even on Ubuntu 20.04). 
I also realized that I can't change the screen brightness any longer. The error log mentions the backlight issue.

I really don't know what to do.
Any suggestions?